# Why is git not uploading the last commit?

Tags: git

I am new to git, and have somehow brok something. It all started with a conflict, then I resolved it, added the file again, and pushed. For my understanding this should be OK. Later I had for a long time a broken version of the project being downloaded when I made a new clone. And when I tried to pull the repository I got a message saying `Already up-to-date.`. So after some thinking I made a small change, committed and pushed again. To test that, I made again a new clone into another directory, and suddenly got the working version without the last small change. Its like the pushes are one version behind the last commit. I have checked the `HEAD` file: `$ cat .git/HEAD` the output was `ref: refs/heads/master` which seems OK to me. I have no real idea where to look.

A friend asked if I have made push with `--force`, well I didn't. (And I have no idea what that would do).

I have tried also downloading a new clone into a new directory, and then simply continue my work there, but the same effect remained, the push is one commit behind.

When I look in bitbucket at the commits I get something like this (M-me, F-friend how is working with me on the project)

```
        F--F--F---
       /          \
 ...--M---------M--M--M
```

---

## Edit

Here are the requested outputs:

```
$ git pull
Password: 
Already up-to-date.
$ git branch -a -v
* master                9247247 [ahead 1] Martin test commit 1. (with -a flag)
  remotes/origin/HEAD   -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master ddb4cbf Another try
$ git log --graph --format=%h
* 9247247
* ddb4cbf
* 9ec3835
* 2c5fd4c
*   e5dd998
|\  
| * 20bc5e1    (* This is the conflict I mentioned *)
| * 04a45a5
| * 7c57c81
* | 1d91307
|/  
* 223948e
* f43648d
*   a5ec578
|\  
| * 4e77b8b    (* This is a test conflict we made, to see how it works *)
* | 20fa9af
|/  
* ffe048d
* 90ea6fc
* 0e529f9
* 1622945
* 2207b8a
```

This caused me to run `git log` and `git show` both show that the last commit is `Martin test commit 1.` But I have made a commit later where I wrote `Martin test commit 2.`

---

## Edit 2

Another wired thing: There is a modified file, but `no changes added to commit`. What? Why? (`git ls-files` shows the index.html file - this means it is staged right?)

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   index.html
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Possible reason: `remotes/origin/HEAD   -> origin/master` but `remotes/origin/master ddb4cbf Another try`. How can I make them point to the same commit?

---

## Edit 3

```
$ git push origin master
Password: 
Everything up-to-date
$ git remote -v
origin  https://martin@bitbucket.org/O....s.git (fetch)
origin  https://martin@bitbucket.org/O....s.git (push)
```

Comment: at what commit is the `origin/master` commit?

Comment: can you paste command output of `git pull origin`?

Comment: Also: `git branch -a -v`, and `git log --graph --format=%h`

Comment: @CharlesB What do you mean in your first question? (The output of what command do you want to see?

Comment: @Martin your output gives the answer: `origin/master` is at `ddb4cbf`, which gives the last commit your remote repository has

Comment: @CharlesB You pointed me in the right direction. Please see the last edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your output shows that you haven't pushed your latest commit, `Martin test commit 1`. Try a `git push`.

`Martin test commit 2` was never committed, or was committed to some other copy of your repo but never pushed. That changeset might also still be in your local directory, try `git status` to see what hasn't been committed yet.

### Edit:

On `no changes added to commit`:
Your local changes need to be staged before being committed, you need to do `git add index.html` before doing `git commit`. You can also just commit all unstaged changes using `git commit -a`

On `git ls-files`: this shows both files in the index and files in the working tree. To see what's staged for commit and what's not, use `git status`.

On remotes: `remotes/origin/HEAD/` is just a pointer to the latest commit in `remotes/origin/master`, hence they are pointing to the same commit already.

Regarding `Everything up-to-date` on `git push`, it's not. Please add the output of `git remote -v`. It could be your remotes are dodgy. Try a `git push origin master` as well.

Comment: `git push` says `Everything up-to-date.`.

Comment: I added the outputs of the things you suggested.

Comment: Something is wrong here. If you `git pull` then `git push` successfully, and you are on the master branch, both your repo and the  remote repo should have the same hash for `master`. Please try this entire workflow and show us all the output: `git commit -a` `git checkout master` `git branch -a -v` `git pull` `git merge` `git commit -a` `git push` `git branch -a -v`